# What is the Node.js equivalent of pywinauto in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pywinauto, equivalent

I have many scripts written in python which use the pywinauto library.  These scripts are opening programs on Windows, doing things within them, etc.  Now that I've begun to learn Node.js, I have only found so far Robot.js, which is certainly promising but lacks the ability I think to get into the nitty-gritty details like pywinauto does.

For example, suppose I wanted to locate a program called "Wordperfect" if it was open or not and if open, kill the program and reopen it.  Here's how I am doing that in python using pywinauto:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

# Starts Wordperfect
wp_open = "wpwin14.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())

if wp_open == False: # detects Wordperfect is closed
    app = Application().start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\WordPerfect Office X4\\Programs\\wpwin14.exe" ')

if wp_open == True: # detects Wordperfect is open
    app = Application().connect(class_name='WordPerfect.14.00') # title=u'WordPerfect X4 - Document1 (unmodified)', 
    wordperfect = app[u'WordPerfect.14.00']
    # Kills Wordperfect
    app.Kill_() 
    # Reopens Wordperfect
    app = Application().start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\WordPerfect Office X4\\Programs\\wpwin14.exe" ')
```

This is just the beginning of my script.  It becomes much more complex from here.  Unfortunately, so far I have not found a specific way to do this within Node.js.  Can anyone let me know if there is and how to do it?  I've been checking out `child-process` in the Node.js documentation but from what I saw in the examples, it's not clear how to recreate what I have in python above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately I found Robot.js which does the same thing on windows except create a bundle of EXE.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs